# drop downlist when I click outside close

Tags: javascript, php, css

iam using this dropdown list plugin;

https://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/index4.html

when I click outside close, i want the dropdown list to close.

its js doc.;

view-source:https://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/js/jquery.dropdown.js

thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin does not have this option. But you can use the ascent of the event. A story on the end element of the handler that will check if there are any items on the list that have been clicked, and then close it

Look at my example...

codepen.io/Hydrock/pen/zPyjQG

Answer (score 0):

```
on you click ul change height and add class cd-active
```

take easy remove class and height

```
$('.cd-dropdown').blur(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('cd-active');
                $('.cd-dropdown ul').css('height', 'auto');
            });
```

***or***

```
$(document).on('blur','.cd-dropdown',function () {
                $(this).removeClass('cd-active');
                $('.cd-dropdown ul').css('height', 'auto');
            });
```

Comment: you can use that in js file and u can use ing same inside this tag <script>code here...</script>
and u need **JQuery CDN** or JQuery file to read this code

Comment: thank you i used it as you said, but it did not work

Comment: `$('.cd-dropdown').focusout(function () {
       $(this).removeClass('cd-active');
       $('.cd-dropdown ul').css('height', 'auto');

       $('.cd-dropdown ul li').css('top', '0px');

   });`

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
$('.cd-dropdown').focusout(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('cd-active');
                $('.cd-dropdown ul').css('height', 'auto');
                $('.cd-dropdown ul li').css('top', '0px');
            });
```

Comment: I am trying now

Comment: i guess, adding to the wrong place, i added in js file after  in <script>....</script> unfortunately not

Comment: look , if you can write this code in html page without file as javascript  , if u create file javascript you don't need to script tag

Comment: such as this using script tag [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)

Comment: yeah I did it like you said, added in -  jquery.dropdown.js

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.cd-dropdown').focusout(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('cd-active');
            $('.cd-dropdown ul').css('height', 'auto');
            $('.cd-dropdown ul li').css('top', '0px');
        });
```

in my js file not like this.
$(this).removeClass('cd-active');  xx

Like this
$(this).removeClass('cd-actives');

I have changed before, noticed afterwards
thank you solved